# PHP cURL follow redirect and get result

Tags: php, curl

If you visit URL:

https://selfsolve.apple.com/agreementWarrantyDynamic.do?caller=sp&sn=990002316140324

then it will redirect and results will be shown at URL:

https://selfsolve.apple.com/wcResults.do

I'm trying with PHP cURL to get this results but the page is empty. Its not redirecting.

Here is my code which I tried:

```
<?php 

$url ='https://selfsolve.apple.com/agreementWarrantyDynamic.do?caller=sp&sn=990002316140324';

$http_headers = array(
                    'Accept: /*',
                    'Connection: keep-alive'
                  );

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $http_headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/applecookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$retValue = curl_exec($ch);
$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
$ee       = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($ee);

print_r($retValue);
?>
```

How to make it work?

Comment: Thanks for your device serial number, by the way.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart My device? Its not my device, do what you want/can with it :) and let me know if you need more. By the way its not Serialnumber.. Its IMEI number

Comment: What do you get in response to print_r($retValue)?

Comment: @button: You can see the result here: http://main.xfiddle.com/da4ed9b6/run.php  it shows the Apple page but its empty. Not showing the results for this device.

Comment: @Cyborg did you have any luck? Did the answer help?

Comment: @button: No :( I have been testing and tweaking your code for hours now. You are right about its a Java form on next URL but I haven't found a way to pass this values to the form. I know other websites are using this URL/method to generate results so it is possible. But I have no luck yet. I highly appreciate your kind help.

Comment: @button: I have also tried to make the script to directly cURL https://selfsolve.apple.com/wcResults.do with form data, but then it got 302 redirect. Maybe there is a way to pass Java from data to this URL?

Comment: To be honest I think you're fighting a losing battle. Each time this remote service changes it's form structure, your service will no longer function. There could also be all sorts of things happening behind the scenes that might prevent this from working for you. If you want a user to see the resulting page in their browser (I'm just guessing) then why not just use an iFrame. Or let them follow a link.

Answer (score 0):

==== (Possible) Issue: Your PHP configuration has `safe_mode` or `open_basedir` enabled.

> CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION (integer) This constant is not available when
>   open_basedir or safe_mode are enabled.(http://php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php)

==== (Possible) Issue: The remote service isn't responding as you expect. Break it down into individual parts and log the output, or check Google Chrome (or similar) for the redirect:

[image: Chrome's view of this...]

**A-ha!** Chrome shows that there is no redirect!

In PHP this might look something like the below. This code will cycle through the redirect chain manually and give you chance to inspect responses along the way.:

```
(see code below)
```

==== Issue: You are executing the request twice (you probably noticed this!):

```
$retValue = curl_exec($ch);
$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
```

==== Issue: You are expecting to `json_decode` a HTML response. This will not work (and can't be expected to).

**IN SHORT**
It looks like there is a redirect in JavaScript that this page is using, as opposed to normal header redirects. You might have to rethink your approach as you'll probably struggle to extract this information from the page, and it's certainly going to be subject to change. (It's actually submitting a form to the next URL so you'll have to work out where the data is from -- again, check the Chrome log).

(footnote) And the code that will help you spot this in PHP (for this URL it returns 200 straight away -- there is no redirect!):

```
    <?php
$url = 'https://selfsolve.apple.com/agreementWarrantyDynamic.do?caller=sp&sn=990002316140324';
$http_headers = array(
        'Accept: */*',
        'Connection: keep-alive',
        'Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch',
        'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6'
);

$finished = false;
$count = 0;//we don't want to redirect forever!
$currentUrl = $url;
while( $finished == false && $count < 10 ) {
        $count++;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $http_headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $currentUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
        // not while we're testing: //curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        $retValue = curl_exec($ch);
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        $responseCode = $info['http_code'];
        if($responseCode > 300 && $responseCode < 303) {
                echo "\n redirecting ($responseCode) to ".$info['redirect_url'];
                $currentUrl = $info['redirect_url'];
        } else {
                $finished = true;
                echo "\n finished ($responseCode) content length:".strlen($retValue);
        }
}


//now try the whole thing

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $http_headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$retValue = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
echo "\nWhole request: finished ($responseCode) content length:".strlen($retValue). " total redirects:".$info['redirect_count'];

echo "\n\n";
```

Output:

```
finished (200) content length:4833
Whole request: finished (200) content length:4833 total redirects:0
```